# Swipe to display a second picture in new viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

My app displays a table view that will open and display a picture on a new ViewController. I am able to send an array of pictures to the new controller, but I cannot figure how to swipe to display a second picture that is part of the array that was sent.  My code is below:

```
var firstchoice: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "Appa1")!,
    UIImage(named: "Appa2")!
]




func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    ///Right way here
    ///You can easily manage using this
    let Vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imageViewController") as! imageViewController



    ///Here you have written four Animal names in Array
    ///So There is going to four case 0,1,2,3 and a default case
    switch indexPath.row
    {
    case 0:
        Vc.passedArray = firstchoice
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
        break;
```

imageViewController code:

```
class imageViewController: UIViewController,GADBannerViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var bannerView: GADBannerView!



    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!


    @IBAction func pictureSwipe(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        let pictureString:String = self.passedArray[index]
        self.myImageView.image = passedArray.first

        index = (index < passedArray.count-1) ? index+1 : 0
    }

    var passedImage : UIImage! = nil
    var passedArray : [UIImage]!

    var index = 0

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.myImageView.image = passedArray.first
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false

        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
```

Comment: You can use NSUserDefaults

Comment: Just to comment on your code overall, you can really tidy up your tableViewDidSelectRow function. Store your images in an array and select the image you want from the array with the index you get from the indexPath.row.

As for how to add the multiple features, you could go about it by creating an array of arrays of the images. [[img1], [img2, img2a], [img3, img3a, img3b]], etc.. and you can grab the specific array from the indexPath.row and pass it to the next VC. 

Like another answer said, you could make it a UIPageController, or you could make a collection view to display the images in

Answer (score 1):

You could setup your second view controller as a UIPageController which has the `swiping` feature built in. Then you just provide an array of images and a `currentIndex` for the selected image. Then the user can swipe through the other related images. You can also add a `UIPageControl` if you like, to show the user that there are more images available.

In the didSelect method in your code there are a few improvements I would suggest:

1. call `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)` after the switch statement to prevent code duplication
2. Use an array for the images and then you can just select the image at indexPath.row
3. Once you have this array you can just pass the whole array and the indexPath to your second vc

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is great insight. However, I am having trouble in my code sending the array of images I declared as 'firstchoice' as a test. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you update your question and add your current code at the bottom?

Comment: updated new code. I figured out how to send an array to viewcontroller, but can't seem to have my swipe function code work correctly.